# different hash length in /etc/shadow

Tags: bash, passwd, hash

Here is the output of `/etc/shadow` for two different users stored on the system:

```
usr1:$1$zgKwt6aQ$gXxsMLgcxa/u6rmq5QseP.:14307:0:99999:7:::
usr2:$6$9Bh5mQ5t$VY64eVcILqgXIC1EFPJ.f3tDVrsSf4y1Th6dleFN2FcuUJQUGevVXILySNfQlDNVWBQXCHaja1hyms.mVeDOY/:14839:0:99999:7:::
```

Question being, why do these passwd hashes (both working) have different length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**usr1** is using a md5 hash indicated by *$1* and **usr2** using sha512 hash indicated by *$6*.

Use `authconfig --test | grep hashing` to see what method is in force now.

The reason **why** is probably that the *usr2* user got added after an OS upgrade where the default algorithm changed from MD5 to SHA512.

See this link for a bit of background:

http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

See cakemox's answer below for all the possible values.

Comment: If not on a Redhat based distro, how to see the method?

Answer (score 3):

They are hashes made using a different algorithm for each user.  The `$1$` and the `$6$` prefixes tell you which hash is being used:

- `$1$` - md5
- `$2$` - bcrypt
- `$2a$` - eksblowfish
- `$5$` - sha-256
- `$6$` - sha-512

Answer (score 1):

There is magic string in the beginning of hash, defining hash format: $number$.